# Can someone tell me whats the encryption in this?

Tags: encryption, http, url

khgpd://zpn.xddspbx.nrf/j/9djwth14tmct9tf/uzdwvrrnonv.tue?gz=0

This is an encrypted text and is most prob a url....pls decode it or tell me which cipher is it, this is not for any security breaches and it is a hint in a cryptic hunt

Comment: What makes you think anything in that URL is encrypted? Could just be a unique identifier. Does not seem long enough to be an encrypted anything.

Comment: @JohnWu: The `khgpf://` instead of `https://` as protocol at the beginning is a hint that this is not a plain URL.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a substitution or byte adding/subtracting cipher, you can try to divine it by using logic.

`khgpd://` does most likely convert to `https://` and `.nrf/` does most likely convert to `.org, .net, .com, etc` while `.tue` likely matches `.htm, .php, .txt, etc`.

However the source of the string would also have the necessary code to encode or decode it, so that is probably a faster solution to solving this. There are other ways such as running the code in a controlled lab and observing the network traffic, but this is a trickier thing to do safely, especially if the string comes from some for of malicious code.